Directory is not removed for file system after Directory.delete
My question is related to this one
I am deleting a folder with Directory.Delete after copy+delete all the files from it -> I am checking it's root folder whether it containing any files -> if not the delete that root folder too.
if (!Directory.Exists(Archivepatz))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Archivepatz);
    foreach (string files in MatrixArchiveFiles)
    {                                   
        string filetocopy = files.Split('\\').Last();
        File.Copy(files, Archivepatz + filetocopy);
        File.Delete(files);
    }
    Directory.Delete(xmlLogfilePathMatrix + MatrixArchiveDay + backslash + MatrixArchiveIP + backslash + MatrixArchiveDMC + backslash, true);
    DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(xmlLogfilePathMatrix + MatrixArchiveDay + backslash);    
    if (!dir2.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any())
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(xmlLogfilePathMatrix + MatrixArchiveDay + backslash))
        {
            Directory.Delete(xmlLogfilePathMatrix + MatrixArchiveDay + backslash, true);
        }
    }
}

It is working properly on my test environment (my laptop), but on the PC it should run the program has the issue like in the linked article -> It says access is denied to the directory I just deleted (the directory is visible also in the Windows explorer, but - like my program - also cannot access it because it does not exist in the file system).
This is what I have tried so far:
Added a break after the Directory.Delete to check what is the situation. Here I found that the deleted folder is still visible but not accessible in the Windows explorer.
Tried to add some wait time between the delete and the "if (!dir2." sections hoping it is enough to dispose the folder.
Tried this solution from the linked article:
"
Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true);
while (Directory.Exists(tempFolder)) Thread.Sleep(0);
"
This resulted in a never ending loop.
Both machines has Windows 10 operating system.
Do you have any idea which Windows component/setting/policy whatever can cause this difference?
Thanks for your support!

Please use variables to store the pathes and also use Path.Combine to build the pathes.

Hi @MatFied: do you think it would help on my issue (in this case, could you please explain), or simply a better general approach?

Buildin pathes by Path.Combine will reduce the chances of wrongtiping. Adding variables will reduce the creation of strings and it will be clearer to read the code.

This is normal OS behavior, tells you that a process is accessing this directory as well.  With delete sharing access, similar to FileShare.Delete in .NET.  The most common case of this, and hardest to diagnose, is that the directory is the default working directory for the process.  Could also be your own process.  Diagnose with SysInternals' Handle utility

Not the solution but a hint. You could use FileSystemWatcher to improve your check over directory existance to avoid loop with Thread.Sleep

@DavideMessori: that was my first intention, but due to the given circumstances it was not possible

@HansPassant: Thanks for the hint. I could accept the situation that someway my own program blocks that directory, the headache is that it is working well on one environment and not on the other.

That reminds me, FileSystemWatcher is another good way to get an undeletable directory.  The OS won't let anybody jerk the floormat that easily.  The larger point is that this just isn't remarkable, you have to write your code to be resilient to the possibility.  If you can't just catch and ignore the exception then consider to send the directory to the recycle bin.

Side note: use Path.Combine to add paths together.
